# Get Coordinates of tile in google map api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In the example below for maptype overlay
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-overlay

I want to get the county names covered under that tile, when I click a tile. I tried attaching event to the overlay object as:

```
var gridOverlay = new CoordMapType(new google.maps.Size(256, 256));
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, gridOverlay);
  google.maps.event.addListener(gridOverlay, 'click', function(evt) {
    // get tile coords 
    console.log(evt);
  });
```

Comment: what does `console.log(evt.latLng);` give you?

Comment: Thanks for comment duncan. That gives me nothing, the event doesn't fire.

Comment: You can't add a click listener to a MapType.  You can only add one to the `google.maps.Map` object.  Rather than the coordinates of the tile, you probably want the bounds of the map.